# How does Opencart store the session_id?

Tags: php, opencart

I'm using opencart version 3.0.3.6.  I wonder, how does the session_id created?

Correct me if I'm wrong.

When I trace the code. when user access the storefront opencart. it will trigger file catalog/controller/startup/session.php on function index(). here will run code:

```
$this->session->start($session_id);
```

this code will run function on file system/library/session.php on function start(); this will trigger code:

```
$this->session_id = $session_id;
```

as I know, that code will trigger insert session_id param throught tabel "oc_session".. but I confuse how to find the query from that code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get session id using this query:

```
$this->session->getId();
```